# Trying to split a sentence into words and delimiters using matchers /\w/ and /\W/

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to split a sentence into words and the parts between the words (I call them delimiters).

```
sentence = "First-tea,-then-coffee!"
=> "First-tea,-then-coffee!"
words = sentence.split(/\W+/) # Splits by non-word characters
=> ["First", "tea", "then", "coffee"]
delimiters = sentence.split(/\w+/) # Splits by word characters
=> ["", "-", ",-", "-", "!"]
```

Splitting into words works fine, but I'm having a question about the delimiters.

**Where does this first empty string come from in the delimiter array?**

Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between start of line `/^/` and first occurrance of `-` there is `"First"`.

So it splits on `"First"` obtaining an empty string `""` and `-`.

Comment: @DanRasmussen If you look delimiters list, you will find `!` at the end. Since `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, do you find `!` in `\w`? No. Then you can't have empty string after `"coffee"`, because you get `!`.

Comment: I agree. Who disagree, who downvoted? Please explain what is wrong with this.

Comment: @mmdemirbas my comment was for Dan Rasmussen who asked why didn't we get empty string after `"coffee"`. Thank you.